# Persist @ManyToOne NULL

Tags: jpa

I have a User class and another Contact which have a relationship between them. This is all working correctly the question that I need to only be recorded a contact if there is any contact attribute filled, but if the user only fill the mandatory user attributes and discard the contact fill precise that in the user table is NULL and not Generating a Contact only with your ID. Mapping the relationship.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
private Contact contact;
```

Comment: If you try to persist a User with the "contact" field as null then it will persist null. Can't get simpler

Comment: When I call the screen display I need the: user.setContact (new Contact ()); If it does not, it will display NULL error when writing and not recording. As I do this new it comes back and fills in the DB with the ID of the contact only, and on the screen the user did not fill anything.

Comment: what your "screen" does is separate to JPA. Focus on the JPA process. You have some objects and you call em.persist. Then you retrieve those object(s) and display them. aka DEBUG it

Answer (score 0):

I have a user registration and the relationship with your contacts. The screen is the user data and the contact data, but by JSF I need to start the contact with a new Contact () if I do not have a null error when writing. When the user persists, the new Contact () will understand that there is a contact and then persistence creating an ID and leaving all other fields empty, since the user did not fill any contacts on the screen.

Until then I created a method in the Contact class which returns if the contact is filled and then in the Service I call the method and if I am not doing a setContact (null), then persisting it saves the user with the contact_id = null as desire whatever.

```
public boolean isNotFilled() {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(email)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(fone)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cell)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```